# FA2 view not working correctly

Tags: smart-contracts, fa2, nft, temple

I've deployed an FA2 token that is supposed to use a token_metadata view to display the token metadata. The view is works fine if you call it directly, but it doesn't seem to be affecting the token metadata.

[image: view token_metadata on better-call.dev]

Temple wallet doesn't seem to detect the token metadata. When I try to add the token, it fails and just leaves the fields blank.

[image: Adding FA2 token to Temple wallet. Temple wallet doesn't automatically detect metadata]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

This is the view return

```
(pair (nat %token_id) (map %token_info string bytes))
```

I've added links to the contract on better-call.dev and the ithacanet explorer

https://better-call.dev/ithacanet/KT1P22gGHCkJMH1PYEXjy5uBpSf3u9XbVbTS/views
https://ithacanet.tzkt.io/KT1P22gGHCkJMH1PYEXjy5uBpSf3u9XbVbTS/storage/149196

Comment: Did you switch the Temple wallet to Ithacanet?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess Temple doesn't recognize the metadata as they don't seem valid.
You can get more information about formatting the token metadata here => https://gitlab.com/tezos/tzip/-/blob/master/proposals/tzip-12/tzip-12.md#token-metadata

Comment: Yeah. I learnt that temple and most indexers only call storage and off-chain views. My view was an on-chain view. Took me a while, but I got it.

Answer (score 1):

The feature on-chain views was added with the Hangzou protocol. But the TZIP for FA2 standard was defined before Tezos had on-chain views. So in the current state the FA2 Token standard does not support on-chain views, thats the reason why Temple wallet fails to load the metadata (and probably other wallets). Because this is a non standard FA2 implementation. You need to work with either:

*A contract can use two methods to provide access to the token-metadata.*

- *Basic: Store the values in a big-map annotated %token_metadata of type (big_map nat (pair (nat %token_id) (map %token_info string bytes))).*
- *Custom: Provide a token_metadata off-chain-view which takes as parameter the nat token-id and returns the (pair (nat %token_id) (map %token_info string bytes)) value.*

*In both cases the “key” is the token-id (of type nat) and one MUST store or return a value of type (pair nat (map string bytes)): the token-id and the metadata defined above.*
*If both options are present, it is recommended to give precedence to the the off-chain-view (custom).*

From:
[FA2 - Multi-Asset Interface](https://tzip.tezosagora.org/proposal/tzip-12/)